# Displaying nested key value paired objects in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

Is there a way to ***display nested key value objects*** in Angular without running into the "ngFor only support iterate arrays error"?

**Example:**

Object A = `[{ "apple": null, "pear": null, "orange": null }]`;

Object B = `[{ "apple": { "label-a": 2.02 }, "pear": { "label-b": 1.99 }, "orange": { "label-c": 1.85 } }]`

Object A is when there is no value for the key data, Object B is where there is. How can both be displayed without causing an angular error? :(

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: "?" optional parameter/chaining in template might help you. Can you please create a stackblitz?

Comment: See stackblitz for ur need https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngqsdj?ctl=1&embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html&hideExplorer=1&view=editor

Comment: Object A
<div *ngFor="let item of A | keyvalue">
 key {{item.key}} and value {{item.value}}
</div>
<br/>
Object B
<div *ngFor="let item of B | keyvalue">
 key {{item.key}} and value
 <strong *ngFor="let innerkey of item.value | keyvalue">
Inner Key {{innerkey.key}} and value {{innerkey.value}}
  </strong>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

```
Object A
<div *ngFor="let item of A | keyvalue">
    key {{item.key}} and value {{item.value}}
</div>
<br/>
Object B
<div *ngFor="let item of B | keyvalue">
    key {{item.key}} and value
    <strong *ngFor="let innerkey of item.value | keyvalue">
Inner Key {{innerkey.key}} and value {{innerkey.value}}
  </strong>
</div>
```

in component.ts

```
 A = new Map<string, string>();
  B = new Map<string, any>();
  constructor() {
    this.setObjectA();
    this.setObjectB();
  }

  setObjectA() {
    this.A.set("apple", null); // a string key
    this.A.set("pear", null); // a numeric key
    this.A.set("orange", null);
  }

  setObjectB() {
    this.B.set("apple", { "label-a": 2.02 }); // a string key
    this.B.set("pear", { "label-b": 1.99 }); // a numeric key
    this.B.set("orange", { "label-c": 1.85 });
  }
```

and stackblitz link [code on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngqsdj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)